# how create index for a raster data which is part of a bigger raster data

Tags: indexing, raster

I have a raster data of 20km and each pixel has an ID (e.g. 1 to 25). I have to devide each pixel in 4 tiles and then relate these two data together. My problem is the new raster data would have its own id (e.g. 1 to 100). However, I want to present the for pixels which are in one pixel with index. For instance if the bigger pixel id is 5 , I say 5a,5b,5c,5d. It is possible to do it manually but it takes a long time for a big data. Is there any approch to do it automatically ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying anything about the language you are using or other context, making it very difficult to answer. But here is an approach in R:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=2)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
r2 <- disaggregate(r, 2)
plot(r2)
plot(as(r2, 'SpatialPolygons'), add=TRUE)
text(r2)
```

You can also link IDs via coordinates, without the need to explicitly store indices

```
xy <- xyFromCell(r2, 1:ncell(r2))
cell <- cellFromXY(r, xy)
cell
```